# How to implement fill attribute in react-native-svg element

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I have a simple triangle drawn with paths/lines, exported from AdobeXD as an SVG, then copied & adjusted SVG code into a react-native project with react-native-svg library elements. I'm trying to fill the background of the element, because I dont want it to be transparent. I thought it would be as simple as using web SVG's `fill` attribute in the G element, but its not working.

Heres the SVG code:

```
<Svg width="22.364" height="20.315" viewBox="0 0 22.364 20.315">
    <G fill="#fff" transform="translate(0.682 0.632)">
        <Line
            id="Line_37"
            data-name="Line 37"
            x1="21"
            y1="12"
            transform="translate(0 7)"
            stroke="rgba(69,74,102, .5)"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-width="1"
        />
        <Line
            id="Line_38"
            data-name="Line 38"
            y2="19"
            transform="translate(21)"
            stroke="rgba(69,74,102, .5)"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-width="1"
        />
        <Line
            id="Line_40"
            data-name="Line 40"
            x1="21"
            y2="7"
            stroke="#fff"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-width="1"
        />
    </G>
</Svg>
```

Looked at `react-native-svg`'s docs and they say "The fill prop refers to the color inside the shape." but like I said, the `fill` prop does not work in either the `<Svg>` element nor the `<G>` element... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `fill` prop on `G` will have an effect on the child elements (the `Line` elements in your case), not on the group as a whole.

You can draw a white rectangle that covers the whole SVG to accomplish what you want:

```
<Svg width="22.364" height="20.315" viewBox="0 0 22.364 20.315">
<Rect
    x="0"
    y="0"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    fill="white"
/>
<G fill="#fff" transform="translate(0.682 0.632)">
    <Line
        id="Line_37"
        data-name="Line 37"
        x1="21"
        y1="12"
        transform="translate(0 7)"
        stroke="rgba(69,74,102, .5)"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-width="1"
    />
    <Line
        id="Line_38"
        data-name="Line 38"
        y2="19"
        transform="translate(21)"
        stroke="rgba(69,74,102, .5)"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-width="1"
    />
    <Line
        id="Line_40"
        data-name="Line 40"
        x1="21"
        y2="7"
        stroke="#fff"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-width="1"
    />
</G>
```